# gSheets horizontal with ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(...))

Tags: arrays, split, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm creating a dashboard in gSheets to report key metrics for A/B tests on my company's billing page. The data auto-pulls from GA via gSheets' addon, and I've decided to dynamically populate the list of tests on the dashboard by using the UNIQUE(...) function. This, in turn, allows metrics matching each test (by name) to pull into the dashboard from the data dump.

---

**Case:** Because it's a dynamic list of tests that will change over time (there are currently 4, there may be 3 next time, or 7, who knows), I've decided to set up the names horizontally with the metrics vertical, like so:

```
 New Users
                 | Test A | Test B | Test C | Test D |
 ----------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 Sessions        |
 Conversions     |
 Conversion Rate |

 Return Users
                 | Test A | Test B | Test C | Test D |
 ----------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 Sessions        |
 Conversions     |
 Conversion Rate |
```

The example above is how I'd like it to look. In reality, the test names are extremely long due to identifying keywords, which help in GA but make it impossible to tell which is which in the spreadsheet dashboard. The test name is at the end.

Here's what I'm working with:
`Optimizely_AB_Test_Alternate_Billing_(Prod)(Property) (AccountNum): devicesImage`

I want to split names on " ", preferably with an arrayformula so it populates horizontally for however many columns have a test. Then I can hide the row with the full name (allowing it to still be used for reference), while displaying the shorter name so people can tell what the test is.

---

**Problem:** I'm stuck trying to make the arrayformula go horizontally,

**Current approach:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A13:13," ")))`

**Current approach output:**

```
                 | coversImage | blank | blank | blank
 ----------------|-------------|-------|-------|-------|
 Sessions        |
 Conversions     |
 Conversion Rate |
```

**Desired output:**

```
                 | coversImage | devicesImage | lifestyleImage | stringCentered |
 ----------------|-------------|--------------|----------------|----------------|
 Sessions        |
 Conversions     |
 Conversion Rate |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume your test names are initially this:

> Optimizely_AB_Test_Alternate_Billing_(Prod)(Property) (AccountNum):
>   devicesImage Optimizely_AB_Test_Alternate_Billing_(Prod)(Property)
>   (AccountNum): coversImage
>   Optimizely_AB_Test_Alternate_Billing_(Prod)(Property) (AccountNum):
>   lifestyleImage Optimizely_AB_Test_Alternate_Billing_(Prod)(Property)
>   (AccountNum): stringCentered

In that case we can extract with regular expressions everything atfer `": "`:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(E26:E29, "(?:\: )(\w*)$")))
```